# How can I transfer or share apps, created in Microsoft app registration portal. I'm using Azure Active Directory and v2.0 endpoint

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I'm using passport-azure-ad library to authenticate people into our app. We are using v2.0 endpoint. I have created multiple applications in Microsoft app registration portal. And have a lot of redirect url's because we have a lot of different environment apps. It was registered under my Microsoft employee account. Now I need to transfer ownership to another developer. How can I do it? Do I need to recreate all this apps in another account? I assume that this will create a new app id's and thus will ask for permissions for all users again. Is there a way to transfer ownership and not recreate all apps again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you created your applications using your Azure Active Directory account (like your Microsoft Employee Account) you will have access to an "Owners" field where you can add new owners to the application which are in the same tenant as you.

If you are trying to transfer an application to a user from a different Tenant or using an MSA account, that is not currently supported, but something that is being considered for the future.

If you need to create a new application id, you will not be able to transfer the consent that you had from the first app over to this second one. That is just not really possible nor something we would look to support due to the security implications.